# How many different armies exist in Warhammer Fantasy?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

I'm following the news about the "Total War: Warhammer" game.

I have seen that they are going to take out the second game and it will include 4 more armies of Warhammer.

In this next edition will put:

- Lizards men
- Skavens
- High Elves
- Dark Elves

These 4 armies would be united to those already existing:

- Empire
- Bretonia
- Chaos warriors
- Beast men
- Dwarfs
- Orcs and goblins
- Vampire counts
- Wood Elves

As for this, I have been thinking about those that are missing... I only have 4 more that would be :

- Chaos Dwarves
- Daemons of Chaos
- Kingdom of the Ogres
- Funeral kings

Exposed all of this, I'm forgetting something? Or are there only these armies in the Warhammer? Could they add some other armies that only comes out in the lore? If so, what would it be?

Comment: From a game perspective, there is probably a limit to the number of races they are likely to add, as it becomes harder to make them play differently and still be balanced.

Comment: @Jack Yes, but I do not intend to seek a competitive balance. I just want to know if there are other races other than those already mentioned, since I do not know if there is more or there is possibility to include armies from within the lore of warhammer fantasy that do not exist in the board game.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Races_and_nations_of_Warhammer_Fantasy?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo , this information is from teh 2005 codex and for example "Nippon - based upon ancient Japan", doesn't really say anything about these nations. But thanks for the link maybe Kislev will be a good point...

Comment: The question is based on opinion, and as such not answerable in current wording. also not in the spirit of this site. asking for what will happen is a big no, no as we simply dont know. Games workshop may or may not make a new race. and that said race may or may not be included in the new game that will be in the new game. or they may decide to flesh out a new army out of existing lore... see, too many possible "speculative" answers.

Comment: @Cherubel I'm not expeculating with the future of the game, I have simply asked about the races or if there was one that i don't has no knowledge of him existence ... If a question like this you think is based on an opinion...

Comment: As Neo already put a link up regarding what exists you can clearly read that you are missing Estalia, TIlea,The Wasteland, Cathay, Nippon, Albion, Araby, Kislev... many of those I just mentioned have some mention in the lore, books, etc. some of them even have units that exist in the Warhammer tabletop game. But to this day none of them have fleshed out standing armies like the ones in your question. so whatever GW will use some of these nations and build a new army around them or invent something entirely new is still speculation and not answerable.

Comment: I think the question is confusing races and armies a bit. For instance, Halflings are a race in Warhammer lore, but I don't think they generally form armies, rather they join with other armies and are unlikely to get their own faction release in the game.

Comment: @Cherubel completly wrong, i know for my experience in wh 40k, the existence of alternative or underdeveloped armies (without codex), with its own rules and lists of official armies, but these are in some cases in secondary magazines or alternative documentation to the main codex. I have already said that an article on a wiki with references to 2005 publications is not the best, because it's been a decade! If I am sorry if I think that "of Eastern origin" does not seem to me a good definition for an entire nation.

Comment: @delinear yes thank you for the comment i fix it  cause i'm looking for armies.

Comment: @Gawey Thank you, that's much clearer to me :)

Answer (score 3):

Its been a while since I've played, and It looks like they have changed things a bit with the latest edition, but I think you have covered all the major published ones.

There did used to be a mercenary army called Dogs of War that you could play, although normally the units were fielded as mercenaries in other armies.

There have also been Araby and Kislev armies in Warmaster, another discontinued game in the same universe. These armies may have had experimental white dwarf rules as well, not sure.

There were also various combined army rules (e.g. Combined chaos armies of various forms), but I wouldn't count them as separate factions, as well as specialised versions of different armies (e.g. rules for different vampire factions that allowed a few different units in the list).

Comment: I was unaware of the existence of Warmaster, but if Araby and Kislev could be good additions ... And yes, I really look for some army that would have appeared in the "white dwarf" or something like this